# Displace 3D vertices along a 2 dimension plane using normals

Tags: algorithm, matrix, geometry

I have this one triangle with arbitrary vertices positioned in a 3D space.

I have that finding the **centroid** of such triangle is easy by doing:

```
float centroid[3] = { 0, 0, 0 };

for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 3; ++j) {
        centroid[i] += points[j][i];
    }
    centroid[i] /= 3.0;
}
```

It's also easy to find the **normal** for it with something called **plane equation**:

```
crossProduct(points[1] - points[0], points[2] - points[0]);
```

There is a very simple method for moving the vertices **away** from the **centroid**, but that is too linear. I can only move the pointers back and forth.

What is the formula that I need to be able to freely move the vertices in a pseudo X/Y axis that is formed from the perspective of the triangle normal?

For reference, I'm using **C++** and **QT** for the vectors and matrices. I'm rendering with basic **OpenGL**.

Comment: This sounds more like a math question than a programming question.

Comment: Do the pseudo x and y axes need to be perpendicular?

Comment: Yes. The axes have to be perpendicular with each other. And, considering this is a math problem, I think I'll post it on math exchange. Thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 1):

To build coordinate axes in triangle plane, you can use axis `pseudoX` from centroid to any vertex and perpendicular axis `pseudoY = pseudoX.cross.Normal`.

The choice of vertex as base vector seems rather natural. If you want to add some randomness, rotate this `pseudoX` by arbitrary angle and generate new `pseudoY` as cross product again.

Another method to generate vector in that plane - from normal only. Choose normal component with the largest magnitude, negate it and exchange with component with the second magnitude, make the smallest component zero. For example, if

```
 |ny|>=|nz|>=|nx|
 Vec = (0, nz, -ny)
```

note that `Vec.dot.Normal = 0`, so `Vec` lies in triangle plane